# SSIS incomprehensible error when loading files

Tags: ssis, dts

I'm facing a very incomprehensible error when loading files through a SSIS package.

[image]

This basically loop on files present in a folder and process them through a DTS 2000.
The job works fine for 99% of my files contained in the folder.
For one particular file, (it's got exactly the same naming syntax as the others) the package fails at the load DTS package's step.
Though if I executes the "Loop on Simucosc db files" content, it passes !! and load correctly all the data.
So it's really when running the whole package that the error appears.
I check with different check points the variables, no differences between a good one and a fail one.

When activating the log in the DTS task, it's only says :

Step Error Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine
Step Error Description:Erreur inattendue du pilote de base de données externe (9499).
Step Error code: 80004005
Step Error Help File:
Step Error Help Context ID:5003000

but that's no help for me.

Does anyone has any idea that can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The path that you are trying to link, import from, or export to has a total character length, including the database name, that is longer than 65 characters.